# blank page is displayed while executing new webapplication

Tags: php, yii

I have downloaded and extracted yii to my webroot folder(var/www/html)
and I have created an new web application using the yii framework (yiic webapp (specified path) and then when I tried to execute the folder after setting the permissions I got an blank page and the webapp application (testdrive <-- application name for example) was not running ...so I added the line in the index.php

```
ini_set('display_errors',1);
```

and when I executed the webapp its showed the following fatal error notification

```
Fatal error: Class 'CInlineAction' not found in /var/www/html/yii/framework/web/CController.php on line 414
```

does anyone know how to solve it and p.s the requirement folder in yii also returns an blank page

Comment: which version of yii? check the path for  `CInlineAction` class is `/web/actions/CInlineAction.php
`

Comment: 1.1.16  is the  yii version im using right now

Comment: your path is correct?

Comment: yeah its there at /web/actions/CInlineAction.php

Comment: Show your controller and your view please

Comment: thanks but i fixed the problem ..i just downloaded yii 1.1.16 zip library which made the problem but when i downloaded the tar.gz file it worked for me just fine